# Django throws TemplateDoesNotExist for a template located it in the 'my_app/templates/my_app' subfolder

Tags: django, django-templates

I am studying Django and got stuck right at the first project.
I've got TemplateDoesNotExist exception when accessing index page of my application. I saw a lot of same looking questions here, but answers seem to be referring to slightly different cases or older Django versions.

Template-loader postmortem shows that Django looked for the index page (index.html) in the 'movies/templates' directory, while file is placed inside 'movies/templates/movies' as it is suggested by manuals.

#### Project info

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM5Zb.png)

'movies' is added to the INSTALLED_APPS list in the settings.py

And movies/views.py refers to the index.html in following way:

```
def all_films(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'movies': my_movies, 'director': settings.DIRECTOR})
```

#### What worked

Adding 'os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'movies', 'templates', 'movies'),' to the TEMPLATES['DIRS'] values in the settings.py makes it work, but after reading manuals and answers to same questions I assume it shouldn't be required.

Also, if I change movies/views.py so that it refers to 'movies/index.html' instead of 'index.html' everything works. But is it a good practice to use app name in links like this? I mean, it could be hard to maintain in future etc.

#### Question

Basically, question is what am I doing/getting wrong.
Could you please suggest, what else should I check to make it work in default state without manual editing of TEMPLATES' DIRS property?

P.S. I am using Django 3.2.7, OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: You need to reference the template as `movies/index.html` in the call to `render`. The reason that it's suggested to duplicate the app name in the templates folder is so that all templates for the app are prefixed with the app's name and this prevents conflicts with templates in other apps

Comment: @IainShelvington I finally modified my code this way (using movies/index.html), thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Check if 'APP_DIRS': True in settings.py>TEMPLATES

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

settings.py

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

views.py

```py
def all_films(request):
    return render(request, 'movies/index.html', {'movies': my_movies, 'director': settings.DIRECTOR})
```

Comment: Yes, with: 

`def all_films(request):
    return render(request, 'movies/index.html', {'movies': my_movies, 'director': settings.DIRECTOR})`
works fine even with 'DIRS': []

I just was not sure about it, because in the tutorial it was just 'index.html'.

Comment: @Alex In the settings.py you specify the path of your templates. Then in your views you can write your templates path after 'templates/.....'

Comment: Here is the Django official documents https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/